# Country_select gem in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am new in rails , tell plz why this code does not work
i use the gem Devise for registration, 
I want to let the user select his country ( with gem country_select )
and when i register new user i put the form:

```
<div id='maintitle'><h1>Sign up</h1></div>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
...
<div class='some_fild'>Email*<br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>
....
<div class='some_fild'>Confirm<br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %></div>

???? <---

<div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
```

I put in my 'user' db table column 'country'

what string i must put instead of "????<---"  to this select seva in my DB in column 'country' ?

i think something like that:

```
<%= f.country_select :country, 'select' %>
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the model and the attribute you want to set - on that form, your model instance is stored inside `resource`, so you'd need this:

I used the example [from the README](https://github.com/stefanpenner/country_select#example), which doesn't make any mention of how to use it inside a form - I'd assume it's the same.